# Redirect to different controller in CI and loading new view

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to `CI`. My problem is as follows:

`ControllerA` loads `login_view`. After successful `login, ControllerA` redirects to `ControllerB` which `loads users_view`

But this `users_view` is get merged with the output of `login_view` which is already on the screen.

How to refresh the `users_view` without getting it mixed with the `login_view`.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show your controllers code?

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect('/controllerB/loaduserview');
```